# OSMdroid add custom icons to ItemizedOverlay

Tags: android, itemizedoverlay, osmdroid

I am using ItemizedIconOverlay class and I'm currently displaying events on the map along with the user's position with the same default icon.

How do I change the icon set for each overlay?

Is there something similar to the google.maps example:

```
    drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);
    drawable3 = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.disruption);
    drawable2 = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_me);

    itemizedOverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(drawable, mapView);
    itemizedOverlay2 = new MyItemizedOverlay(drawable2, mapView);
    itemizedOverlay3 = new MyItemizedOverlay(drawable3, mapView);
```

I had each itemizedOverlay have its own marker...

How do I do this with Open Street Maps?

```
mResourceProxy = new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(getApplicationContext());
this.mMyLocationOverlay = new ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>(mItems, new Glistener(), mResourceProxy);
```

Thank you for your help and its a shame not much support is available online for this open source project ...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Presumably your mItems is an ArrayList of OverlayItems created like:

```
mItems = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
```

To this list you will be adding individual OveralyItems, so when you create each item you can do it like this, setting the marker before you add it to the list:

```
OverlayItem olItem = new OverlayItem("Here", "SampleDescription", point);
Drawable newMarker = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mymarker);
olItem.setMarker(newMarker);
mItems.add(olItem);
```

where mymarker is a .png in your drawables folder.

**Update** - to set default marker for whole overlay, change

```
this.mMyLocationOverlay = new ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>(mItems, new Glistener(), mResourceProxy);
```

to

```
this.mMyLocationOverlay = new ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>(mItems, newMarker, new Glistener(), mResourceProxy);
```

where newMarker is as before

Comment: But can I add a default marker for the whole overlay? Like itemizedOverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(drawable, mapView);

and then each item added to that overlay gets the specific marker.

Comment: Yes, it appears there is another constructor available which takes a default marker as well. I'll edit my answer with an update

Comment: The problem that I'm having is that my custom markers look extremely big :/