# How to make such a custom marker? osmdroid

Tags: android, osmdroid

How to make such a custom marker?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Firstly use  `BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(id goes here)`

Then add marker to the map using

```
Marker marker = GoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng)
                                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(id goes here));
```

For the text you can use

```
marker.setTitle(string);   //text on top
marker.setSnippet(string); //text below the title
```

Comment: The text itself is offset relative to the overlay. And is in a white oval. I use osmdroid.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533071/osmdroid-add-custom-icons-to-itemizedoverlay see this solution

Comment: The question is tagged `osmdroid`.